# Display the current time of the device when a message is sent by the user

Tags: swift

How can I show the time near a message when it was sent by the user?

I have tried using `TimeInterval()` and `DateFormatter()` but I haven't been able to implement them successfully. Also I am using a xib file for the message cell.

Comment: Use `Date()` instead of `TimeInterval()`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Date and DateFormatter to get current date and time.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
formatter.string(from: Date()) // Example: 19:38:20

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
formatter.string(from: Date()) // Example: 2019/07/07


// Or you can use dateStyle and timeStyle.

formatter.dateStyle = .long
formatter.timeStyle = .medium
```

Comment: Don't hardcode formats. Use dateStyle and timeStyle so the result appears properly for the user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

What is your backend? If you are using firebase, you can add a variable to the post called "timestamp" from there you can retrieve how long since that post was made, then you can easily get the local time and minus it from the time since it was posted. Give me more information about your stack and I might be able to give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your message data model you could store a property for the messageTime as a Date object instead of a string(fetched from server) using a DateTransfrom. Now when you want to display that message date you could convert that messageTime Date object to a string with your own format for displaying using a DateFormatter. I am using a mapper here to map the json object to my data model object

```
public class Message:Mappable{
    public var text: String 
    public var messageTime: Date 
    public var id: String 

    required public init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required convenience public init?(map: Map) { self.init() }    

    open override func mapping(map: Map) {
        text <- map["text"]
        messageTime <- (map["created_at"], DateTransform())
        id <- map["id"]
    }
}

Then fetch the 'message' object.

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" //07:30 PM
let messageTimeString = dateFormatter.string(from: message.messageTime)
```